# Shortcut Key to Navigate from Code-Behind to SourceView

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am Looking for a Shortcut Key to navigating from **Code-Behind** file(a.cs) to **HTML Source-View** page(a.aspx)?

i couldn't find any direct possible way to handle this!

Answer (score 3):

**F7** -> Toggle between .ASPX and .ASPX.CS (Code Behind)
**Shift + F7** -> Toggle between .ASPX's Design View and Source View

@JasonReis, you're right

Answer (score 1):

Try Shift + F7
Usually using the shift + shortcut key does the opposite function in visual studio

Answer (score 0):

F7 allows me to toggle between the .aspx and the .cs files.

Comment: F7 works correct movign from aspx to cs but from cs when i press F7 moves me to Design View not Source View. i use only source Code view not Design view!

Comment: What if you click the Source button located in the lower left corner?  Then pressing F7 should toggle between Code and Source view.  It does for me anyway. ;)

Comment: @JasonReis that is not funny... Does anyone really know how to go to the source view? is there any extension or plugin? thanks.